# Doubts & Concerns About Deploying My App on the Apple App Store

Tags: ios, flutter, app-store

I started learning flutter 3 months back & with hard work & determination, I have successfully finished learning it. And now I am excited to deploy my dream app on the Google Play Store.

However, I also want to make my app available on the Apple App Store. But I don’t have the resources to get a MacBook & iPhone as I am already in huge college debt. Fortunately, a friend of mine owns both a MacBook and an iPhone and can lend me for a few days.

Now, I have some doubts and questions:-
1.) Is it possible for me to use someone else's MacBook and iPhone to develop and deploy apps on the App Store? Are there any potential objections from Apple, such as concerns about reduced sales or other issues?

2.) Are there any unforeseen challenges or complications that could arise from using someone else's equipment for app development and deployment?

3.) From the perspective of using Flutter, could I encounter any specific issues or hurdles in the process?

By the way, are there alternative methods or solutions for deploying apps on the Apple App Store that I should consider?

Thank you and best regards.

Comment: Access to a Mac is a requirement. You can use Mac-in-cloud solutions, but while that may work for building and delivering your app to the App Store, it isn't very convenient for developing and testing and future enhancements. Even though you have a flutter app, which is cross platform, you will need to test it on a real iOS device to make sure it works correctly. Apple don't care who owns the device you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Does Apple care who owns the Mac/iPhone - No
2. Implementations if using rented equipment - availability of equipment wjen you need it again, unathorized access to you Apple Dev Account by the owner of the device (you have delete your stuff before returning)
3. App Store Publishing - nothing Flutter specific, no one cares if it is Flutter or Swift as long as the guidelines are met

I would also factor in the cost of Apple Dev subscription whoch starts at $99/year